# Use either one flag argument or two positional arguments with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

i'm stuck on a task, which require either 2 positional args or 1 (a file) if flag enabled:

```
parser.add_argument('pos_arg1', help='desc')
parser.add_argument('pos_arg2', help='desc')
parser.add_argument('--add_arg1', help='desc', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='?')
```

so using the script with either `script.py arg1 arg2` or `script.py --add_arg1 file` are both valid. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define:

```
In [422]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [423]: g=parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
In [424]: g.add_argument('--foo')
In [426]: g.add_argument('bar',nargs='*',default='test')

In [427]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython2.7 [-h] [--foo FOO | bar [bar ...]]

positional arguments:
  bar

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO

In [429]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[429]: Namespace(bar='test', foo=None)

In [430]: parser.parse_args(['one','two'])
Out[430]: Namespace(bar=['one', 'two'], foo=None)

In [431]: parser.parse_args(['--foo','two'])
Out[431]: Namespace(bar='test', foo='two')
```

With this you can specify two (really any number) of unlabeled values, or one value flagged with `--foo`.  It will object if I try both.  I could have marked the group as `required`.

A couple of notes:

Marking `--foo` as `nargs='?'` is relatively meaningless unless I specify both a `default` and `const`.

I can only specify one one positional in the exclusive group, and that argument has to have '?' or '*', and a 'default'.  In other words, it has to genuinely optional.

Without the mutually_exclusive_group I could make both positionals `?`, but I can't say 'zero or two arguments'.

Comment: so, there is no solution?

Comment: To make it accept 2 positionals or one flagged argument, but not both?  The solution is to let the parser accept both, and write your own code to complain afterwards.