# argparse: Require either one flag or 2+ positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program that can either take one flag-argument `--list` **OR** two or more positional arguments `SOURCE [SOURCE ...] DESTINATION`. Ideally with when `SRC/DST` is used it should also accept `--recursive` but that can be a global option simply ignored with `--list`.

For now I have this:

```
group = parser.add_argument_group('Source / Dest Selection')
group.add_argument('--list', action="store_true") 
group.add_argument('--recursive', action="store_true") 
group.add_argument('SOURCE', nargs='+') 
group.add_argument('DESTINATION')
```

However it always requires SOURCE and DESTINATION. I don't want to make *each* optional, instead I would like to either require *both* `SRC` and `DST` or *none* of them and then require `--list`.

I would also settle for *both or none* of SRC/DST and simply ignore them if `--list` was used.

Any idea how to express that with `argparse`? Thanks!

Comment: As written 'DESTINATION' is a required positional, and thus can't be part of MEXgroup.  'SOURCE' is also required.  A MEXgroup can only handle one positional (a '*' (with default) or '?').

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, so how can I make the whole group optional but if the group is used both positionals must be there?

Comment: If you define one positional with '*', then you can check things after parsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use either one flag argument or two positional arguments with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273663/use-either-one-flag-argument-or-two-positional-arguments-with-argparse)

Answer (score 0):

Very hackish but you could use multiple parsers. May be something like:

```
import argparse

parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser1.add_argument('--list', action="store_true")
parser1.add_argument('DUMMY_POSITIONAL', nargs='*')
args1 = parser1.parse_args()

if not args1.list:
  parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser2.add_argument('SOURCE', nargs='+')
  parser2.add_argument('DESTINATION')
  args2 = parser2.parse_args()
  if len(args2.SOURCE) == 0:
    print("Must specify SOURCE")
  else:
    print(args2.SOURCE, args2.DESTINATION)
```